# large number of inner joins within the same table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where all the items are in one table named "table". I am doing this for two items:

```
SELECT I.A + J.A AS A, I.B + J.B AS B, I.C + J.C AS C FROM table AS I
INNER JOIN Table AS J
ON I.StartDate = J.StartDate
AND I.EndDate  = J.EndDate
WHERE I.ItemId = 602028
AND   J.ItemId = 602029
```

and I doing this for three items in the table:

```
SELECT I.A + J.A + K.A AS A, I.B + J.B + K.B AS B, I.C + J.C + K.C AS C FROM table AS I
INNER JOIN Table AS J
   ON I.StartDate = J.StartDate
  AND I.EndDate   = J.EndDate
INNER JOIN Table AS K
   ON I.StartDate = K.StartDate
  AND I.EndDate   = K.EndDate
WHERE I.ItemId    = 602028
  AND J.ItemId    = 602029
  AND K.ItemId    = 602030
```

So now you have an idea of what I am trying to do; straightforward. Here is the issue. The number of items to join is supplied at run time, and this number can be large, up to 200. My question is: what is the most efficient way to do this? Currently it's starting to get ugly at more than 5 joins.

Comment: I think your second example should be updated with 3rd item if am not wrong

Comment: Do you always know in advance how many "jumps" are involved to get from the first to the last entry? Are they always consecutive as in this example?

Comment: @Anand Yes, i missed out WHERE J.ItemId  = 602029

Comment: @Joachim Yes, the user supplied 10 items for example, so I have to join all 10

Comment: but where is the `J.itemid` if i get it right.And from previous comment, all 10 is same table

Comment: All items are in the same table yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to alias and pivot as I don't think you need it.

Example to try ..

```
declare @table table (ID int, A int, B int, C int, startdate date, enddate date)

insert @table (ID, A, B, C, startdate, enddate)
select 123, 1, 1, 1, '2014-10-10', '2014-10-10'
union all
select 456,2, 2, 2, '2014-10-10', '2014-10-10'
union all
select 789,3, 3, 3, '2014-10-10', '2014-10-10'
union all
select 111,4, 4, 4, '2014-10-11', '2014-10-11'
union all
select 222,4, 4, 4, '2014-10-11', '2014-10-11'


select sum(A) as A, sum(B) as B, sum(C) as C, startdate, enddate
from @table
where ID in (123,456,789, 111, 222)
group by startdate, enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this !

```
Select sum(a)as A, sum(b) as B,sum(c) as C from
(select itemid,a,b,c from table t 
where itemid in (602028,602029,...) 
    and exists (select 'x' from table t1 where itemid in (602028,602029,...) and t.startdate=t1.startdate and t.enddate=t1.enddate))a
```

Comment: The corresponding columns are sum for each item, not a simple scalar multiplication...

Comment: Please refer my updated answer while i try form query for you

Comment: pivot looked like the way to go...have to think about it

Answer (score 0):

You could try a union on the tables in a derived table and use sum() on the columns for the selected Dates and Item

I.E

```
SELECT *
FROM I,
(SELECT SUM(A), SUM(B), SUM(C) 
FROM (SELECT * FROM I UNION
SELECT * FROM J UNION
SELECT * FROM K) UnT

WHERE UnT.STARTDATE = I.STARTDATE 
AND UnT.ENDDATE = I.ENDDATE
AND UnT.ItemId = I.ItemId
AND I.ItemId = 602028
```

Now you just have to Union the new table in the derived table.

Comment: The table name is "table" only one table is involve here